# PowerApps: Filter a Lookup Field Based on a Previous Field

Tags: filter, lookup, powerapps

I have two lists w/ the following details:

```
List 1: JobType1; Column: Title
List 2: JobType2; Columns: Title, JobType1 (lookup of Title column of List 1)
```

On List 3 (Request), I am trying to use PowerApps and I have two fields that are lookups of the two lists:

```
JobType1 - lookup field that uses the Title column of List 1
JobType2 - lookup field that uses the Title column of List 2
```

I am trying to filter JobType2 field in the form to display all values on the Title column on List 2 that matches the value of the JobType1 field in the form w/ the JobType1 column on List 2.

I tried using this formula but it does not work. Please help me.

```
Filter(Choices(IntMktg.Job_x0020_Type_x0020_2), Value in Filter('JobType1', IntMktg.Job_x0020_Type_x0020_1 = DataCardValueClient.Text).Title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combo box control doesn't display the result. It seems a bug. I tried it out with  the 3 lists and created a form on JobRequest. Here is my formula and it works if you use a dropdown. while waiting for Combo box to be fixed, you can use dropdown instead of Combo box.

```
Filter(Choices(JobRequest.JobType2), Id in Filter([@JobType2], JobType1.Value = DataCardValue2.Selected.Value).ID)
```

Comment: Thanks @user10199063. Can you enlighten me a bit since I am pretty new to PowerApps? JobRequest.JobType2 is the name of the lists/form and the field that I am wanting to have the filter? And if I add drop down fields to replace the combo fields, how to I connect them to the appropriate columns and use them on the formula you provided?